# Stand clear sign on Soyuz capsule underside

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft

This is a photo of the soyuz capsule posted by the asker of a previous question. One of the labels reads "Not to stand near this side". What is the reason for this? Is it because of active ionizing or RF radiation sources on that side? Or a caution against the possibility of yet not fired retro rocket?

[image]

Comment: My first thought was residual heat, but I guess the heat shield itself has been jettisoned by this point, so the next most obvious concern would be one of the retros firing late due to malfunction. It seems odd that the bystander instructions would be on the bottom, since I'd expect it to normally land bottom-down (unless the chute positioning is specifically designed otherwise).

Comment: @RussellBorogove i believe it usually lands and then tumbles a few times.

Comment: [This page](http://www.svengrahn.pp.se/histind/Ugol/Ugol.html) by Sven Grahn postulates it might be due to "radiation from the gamma-ray sources that are used as 'transmitters' for the backscatter 'altimeter' that triggers the soft-landing retro-rockets".

Comment: Also, [this document](http://www.spaceref.com/iss/soyuz/SCLSaB.edit.pdf) gives some insight about the dangers around the landed capsule.

Comment: @Bryan Lynch great finds !

Comment: I wonder if any of the soft-landing retro-rockets could fire late as well... (especially if a person within range gets detected as the ground).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original wording above says "Do not stand in front of the bigger head".
Two reasons:

1. There is a [Kaktus precision gamma-ray altimeter](http://www.spacesafetymagazine.com/spaceflight/reentry-descent-landing/soft-landing-on-kaktus/) (Containing <sup>60</sup>Со or  <sup>137</sup>Сs).
2. There is a chance of one of the soft landing engines firing late due to malfunction.